# Exponential Bound on Nonlinear Dynamic System

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

Consider the nonlinear system described by
\begin{equation*}
\dot{z_1}=-z_1, \quad \dot{z_2}=z_1^2+2z_1\gamma-z_2,
\end{equation*}
where $\gamma\in\Gamma=[\gamma_{min},\gamma_{max}]\subset(0,\infty)$ fixed.

I am interested in finding $\epsilon_0>0$, $\lambda>0$ and $m\geq 1$ such that the following holds for all $\gamma\in\Gamma$:
\begin{equation*}
\text{If} \quad \|z(0)\|\leq \epsilon_0, \quad \text{then} \quad \|z(t)\|\leq m e^{-\lambda t}\|z(0)\|.
\end{equation*}

As a starting point, I thought of solving the first equation, which trivially gives
\begin{equation}
z_1(t)=z_1(0)e^{-t}.
\end{equation}
Then, substitute this in the second equation, yelding
\begin{equation}
\dot{z_2}=z_1(0)^2e^{-2t}+2z_1(0)e^{-t}\gamma-z_2(t)\leq \epsilon_0^2e^{-2t}+2\epsilon_0e^{-t}\gamma_{max}-z_2(t).
\end{equation}
But, at this point, I have no idea on how to proceed.

Comment: Solving for $z_2$ isn't that hard either. Tried that?

Comment: You mean solving
$$\dot{z}_2=z_1(0)^2e^{-2t}+2z_1(0)e^{-t}\gamma-z_2(t)?$$

Comment: yes. Just solve $\dot z_2 + z_2 = 0$ first. It'll be like $z_2 = z_2(0)\cdot e^{-t}$. Now you know that $z_2(t) = Ae^{-2t}+(Bt+C)e^{-t}$ for some $A, B, C$

Comment: If I solve for $z_2$, I get:
$$z_2(t)=e^{-t}z_2(0)+z_1(0)^2e^{-t}(1-e^{-t})+2z_1(0)\gamma te^{-t}$$, but still I need something to find $m,\lambda$ and $\epsilon_0$, maybe some growth bound